# How browser engine store Css values and using it?

Tags: css, browser, webkit, gecko, blink

I am trying to write an browser engine from scratch.
I wonder how browser engines store css values and using it. I look into blink source code and I think at first there are property-value string-string pairs and then it turns into some structs called ComputedStyle. But I still didn't understand how blink use them. I mean does blink store css values in render object or it does only store those values in cssom. At last why browser engines need both store css values as string, store css values as enumaration(some of them) in cssom, store necessary css values in render object? Isn't it possible these three combined to one?

Comment: A browser must at minimum keep track of declared values, specified values, computed values, used values and actual values of elements, boxes and fragments for each property, all of which have the potential to be different. Retaining each of those values close to where they are needed and avoiding the performance cost of recomputation is a necessity.